# parsing xml response and inserting into table

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am consuming a soap base service which is returning xml datset as response , here is the below sample response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getShipUpdatesResponse xmlns="http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/">
         <getShipUpdatesResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Tracking">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="rowId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="awbNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Activity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Details" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Location" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
               <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                  <Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                     <rowId>99438814</rowId>
                     <awbNo>290012097109</awbNo>
                     <Date>12 Nov 2017 15:47</Date>
                     <Activity>DATA RECEIVED</Activity>
                     <Details>Online Data Submitted</Details>
                     <Location>Riyadh</Location>
                  </Tracking>
                  <Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                     <rowId>99438812</rowId>
                     <awbNo>290012097092</awbNo>
                     <Date>12 Nov 2017 15:47</Date>
                     <Activity>DATA RECEIVED</Activity>
                     <Details>Online Data Submitted</Details>
                     <Location>Riyadh</Location>
                  </Tracking>
               </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </getShipUpdatesResult>
      </getShipUpdatesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to parse the response via `EXTRACTVALUE` however i  am facing below issue

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '//diffgr:diffgram/text()'
```

Below is the query i am trying to get all the values from Tracking element

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE('<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getShipUpdatesResponse xmlns="http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/">
         <getShipUpdatesResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Tracking">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="rowId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="awbNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Activity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Details" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Location" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
               <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                  <Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                     <rowId>99438814</rowId>
                     <awbNo>290012097109</awbNo>
                     <Date>12 Nov 2017 15:47</Date>
                     <Activity>DATA RECEIVED</Activity>
                     <Details>Online Data Submitted</Details>
                     <Location>Riyadh</Location>
                  </Tracking>
                  <Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                     <rowId>99438812</rowId>
                     <awbNo>290012097092</awbNo>
                     <Date>12 Nov 2017 15:47</Date>
                     <Activity>DATA RECEIVED</Activity>
                     <Details>Online Data Submitted</Details>
                     <Location>Riyadh</Location>
                  </Tracking>
               </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </getShipUpdatesResult>
      </getShipUpdatesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'), '//diffgr:diffgram/text()','xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"') AS mydata
            FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 issues here:

1. You need the `diffgr` namespace declared in your namespace statement. You can add it along with the existing one, like

   ```
   'xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"'
   ```
2. Your example diffgram nodes don't have any `text` subnodes. If they did, they'd look more like `<diffgr:diffgram>Here's a text node</diffgr:diffgram>`. Instead, they only contain XML nodes. So `text()` will be null. If you're trying to view the XML contents of the diffgram nodes, use `EXTRACT` instead. This example will extract all of the subnodes:

   ```
   select EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('...your xml...'), 
         '//diffgr:diffgram/*',
         'xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"'
       ) AS mydata
       FROM dual
   ```

Also, as a side note, [Oracle has deprecated EXTRACT and EXTRACTVALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACTVALUE.html#GUID-20AB974B-7544-4F44-B539-787FB6145680), and recommends that you use XMLTABLE or one of their other functions instead. Just something to be aware of for the future.

Comment: what if i want to return all 4 columns separately to insert into a table